# Can we configure Devel module to pick up images for the image field of a content type only from a specific directory containing images?

Tags: nodes, media, debugging

A **Yes** or **No** question.
Using *Drupal 7.43*. *Devel* module generates polycolor image content of a content-type which has an *image* field. But I need only a few specific images on my contents of that content type and I need Devel module to pick up images from a specific directory on my system(in the same drupal environment directory) and then randomly associate them with contents. Can this be done by changing **Devel's configurations**? Suggestions are welcome for alternative solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

There are at least two modules providing this or similar features:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/realistic_dummy_content
- https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_image_provider

HTH